# Removing a column in EF Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to change my products to use tags instead of categories. Implementing the tags was quite easy, but as soon as I remove the category from the product model, I'm starting to get errors.

Simply put I have the following classes:

```
public class BaseProduct
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public int CategoryID {get;set;}
    public virtual Category Category {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<ProductTag> Tags {get;set;}
}

[Table("Products")]
public class Product : BaseProduct
{
    public string ImageUrl {get;set;}
}

[Table("Packages")]
public class Package : BaseProduct
{
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products {get;set}
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryID {get;set;}
    public string CategoryName {get;set;}
    public int ParentID {get;set;}
    public virtual Category Parent {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection Products {get;set;}
}

public class ProductTag
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ProductId {get;set;}

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string TagName {get;set;}

    public virtual BaseProduct Product {get;set;}

    public virtual Tag Tag {get;set;}
}

public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public virtual Collection<ProductTag> ProductTags {get;set;}
}
```

I am doing this on model creating:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Package>().HasMany(p => p.Products).WithMany(p => p.Packages)
        .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("PackageRelations");
                m.MapLeftKey("PackageID");
                m.MapRightKey("ProductID");
            });
    modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
                .HasOptional(c => c.Parent)
                .WithMany(c => c.Children)
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentID);
    modelBuilder.Entity<BaseProduct>()
                .HasRequired(p => p.Category)
                .WithMany(c => c.Products)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoryID);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ProductTag>()
                .HasRequired(c => c.Product)
                .WithMany(c => c.Tags)
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.ProductId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ProductTag>()
                .HasRequired(c => c.Tag)
                .WithMany(c => c.ProductTags)
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.TagName);
}
```

This is all working fine, and I get the following tables in my DB:

- BaseProducts
- Categories
- PackageRelations
- Packages
- Products
- ProductTags
- Tags

But if I edit BaseProduct and remove category id and the virtual category, like this:

```
public class BaseProduct
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<ProductTag> Tags {get;set;}
}
```

And remove the virtual products from the category:

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryID {get;set;}
    public string CategoryName {get;set;}
    public int ParentID {get;set;}
    public virtual Category Parent {get;set;}
}
```

And remove the mappings from OnModelCreating:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Package>().HasMany(p => p.Products).WithMany(p => p.Packages)
        .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("PackageRelations");
                m.MapLeftKey("PackageID");
                m.MapRightKey("ProductID");
            });
    modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
                .HasOptional(c => c.Parent)
                .WithMany(c => c.Children)
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentID);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ProductTag>()
                .HasRequired(c => c.Product)
                .WithMany(c => c.Tags)
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.ProductId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ProductTag>()
                .HasRequired(c => c.Tag)
                .WithMany(c => c.ProductTags)
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.TagName);
}
```

Then, when I go to a page that uses the product model, I am getting the following error:

**Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.**

**Exception Details: System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:**

**BaseProduct: : The referenced EntitySet 'BaseProduct' for End 'BaseProduct' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
BaseProduct: : The referenced EntitySet 'BaseProduct' for End 'BaseProduct' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I got the error because I removed the part of the modelbuilder that built the model for BaseProduct. I did not know it was required, but I changed

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductTag>()
            .HasRequired(c => c.Product)
            .WithMany(c => c.Tags)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ProductId);
```

to

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BaseProduct>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Tags)
            .WithRequired(t => t.Product)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.ProductId);
```

and then it was working again